# div height position not working

Tags: css, html, inheritance

I am having problems working on a project for school, what we are doing is creating div sections. And within each div section I color coded them to see them more clear. Though in my leftnav div it will not branch down to the bottom to the footer. JSFIDDLE here- http://jsfiddle.net/rM8zw/

if someone could help me fix this and explain what i did wrong? I have three container divs, so that some of my inherits would work correctly. Container for leftnav and bodyline, container for main site, container for BmiddleLeft and Right. Thanks guy ahead of time.

I am trying to figure out why my #leftnav will not complete its height to my bodyline so it is even.

heres the CSS-

```
#container{
    width:980px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:900px;
    min-height:900px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    boder: solid 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#holder{
    width:980px;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 800px;
    min-height:800px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto; 
    border: solid 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#FFF;
}
#header{
    width:980px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#FF0000;
}
#navbar{
    width:980px;
    height:40px;
    border:solid 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#c0c0c0;
}
#bodycontainer{
     width:980px;
     height:800px;
     min-height:800px;
     height:auto !important;
     overflow:hidden;
}
#leftnav{
     float:left;
     width:200px;
     height:1200px;
     min-height:1200px;
     height:auto !important;
     padding:0;
     overflow:hidden;
}
#bodyline{
     float:right;
     width:780px;
     height:800px;
     min-height:800px;
     height:auto !important;
     background:#00FF40;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

heres the HTML I am currently using-

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="holder">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
    </div>
    <div id="bodycontainer">
        <div id="leftnav">
        </div>
        <div id="bodyline">
            <div id="Btop">
            </div>
            <div id="BmiddleCont">
                <div id="BmiddleLeft">
                hello
                <br />
                </div>
                <div id="BmiddleRight">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Bbottom">
            </div>
            <div id="BbottomLast">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this is a little better.

Comment: You should reword your question in a way that is useful to other users, not just yourself

Comment: You need to work on clarifying your question.

Comment: What do you mean reword? I specified everything that is needed. I figured maybe my container divs where messing up. My leftnav section will not height:auto !important. So then i tried making a container for it and for my bodyline, thus creating my leftnav to inherit the containers height, though it will not flow with auto !important on my bodylines height. If you look at my jsfiddle you'll see what I meant. Don't really think it deserved a negative vote, hence stackoverflow is a place to ask questions. Learn from our mistakes

Comment: Also since I am a new user, and the comments i have recieved seem to be from uptight snobbs who seem to think they are the best. Instead of critiquing my format, explain instead of reword plainly. I worded everything as needed. I need an explaination on why my leftnav div is not adjusting its height.

Comment: If you set the `min-height` as `inherit`, then it will go up until it finds a value. In this case, up to `#container`, which has it set to `900px`. That's why the `height` of your `leftnav` is only `900px`. `min-height` overrides `height`. Furthermore, if you take `min-height` out and keep `height: auto`, then you have no restrictions imposed on the `height`, so the `height` of your `leftnav` becomes the `height` of its content. Which is `0` in this case.

Comment: Ok I am understanding that a little more now Ana. so when typing inherit it will seek a value of height. Got that. So what should i do to keep it's height of my bodyline, Since in fact it will not be colored after reporting it to class. If i took all colors out of the bodyline divs and leftnav div, and created a background container it should look smooth correct?

Comment: I've put it all into a proper answer with links to possible solutions. If you're interested to know why is it so difficult to have equal height columns in CSS, then you might want to watch this presentation http://fantasai.inkedblade.net/weblog/2012/css-layout-evolution/ Another observation I have to make is that half the CSS you have in that fiddle is redundant. Plus, you have `!important` in your styles, which you really shouldn't use unless you want to overwrite some inline rules that you have no control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `min-height` as `inherit`, then it will go up until it finds a value. In this case, up to `#container`, which has it set to `900px`. That's why the `height` of your `#leftnav` is only `900px`. `min-height` overrides `height`. Furthermore, if you take `min-height` out and keep `height: auto`, then you have no restrictions imposed on the `height`, so the `height` of your `leftnav` becomes the `height` of its content. Which is `0` in this case.

There are a few ways in which you could set its `height`. The easiest one of all, since you are explicitly setting heights on all the elements on the right, would be to add them up and then explicitly set that resulted value as the `height` of your `leftnav`.

If those values are just dummy values and the heights of the elements on the right will depend on the `height` of the content in them, then you have a couple of options:

**1.** Actually setting the `height` of your `#leftnav` to the `height` of its parent (`#bodycontainer`). You do that by setting its `position` to `absolute` (and don't forget to set `position: relative` on the parent) and its top, left, bottom values to 0. In this case, you'll also have to set the `padding-left` of its parent (`#bodycontainer`) to the same value as `#leftnav`'s `width` (`200px` here). Or set `left-margin: 200px;` on its sibling (`#bodyline`) to avoid having to modify the `width` of `#bodycontainer` or to set its [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) to `border-box`. - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/rM8zw/2/)

**2.** Make it look like it has the same `height`.

**a)** The easy method. Use a [**`gradient`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient) with color stops as the `background` of the parent (`#bodycontainer`) - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/rM8zw/3/) // [**demo without redundant code**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/rM8zw/11/)

```
background: linear-gradient(left, #FF00FF 200px, transparent 200px);
```

Keep two things in mind:

- one, you'll have to add prefixes, as gradients are not yet supported unprefixed
- two, this won't work in IE9 or older

(*see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) for more details*)

**b)** The best compatibility method (works in IE8+). Use a [**pseudo-element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements) on the parent, `#bodycontainer`, position it absolutely, set its `top`, `left` and `bottom` values to `0`, give it `#leftnav`'s `width` and the desired `background`. - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/rM8zw/4/) // [**demo without redundant code**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/rM8zw/12/)

```
#bodycontainer:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: #f0f;
    content:'';
}
```

Comment: Redundant code, do you mean the constant margin,padding, and so forth? i see that you added a div {} code, which in turn would get rid of my repeative use of the same styling? Looks alot cleaner and the weight of the file won't be so big, as well. Thanks I understand that a little more. Gradients I do not use, since I use IE because I am on another persons computer right now. i usually use Mozilla software. Ive never used pseudo before or after. Though I see what you did in the element. Only reason I did not want a set height is because it will change. with a floating div inside it.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to those. And that's what the `div` rule set at the beginning is for. I removed all the `width: auto` and the `width: 100%` rules as well. By default, divs have `width: auto`, which means the `width` of their parent minus any paddings the parent might have. If the parent has `padding:0`, then 100% and auto are the same (and the default for block elements) - check this http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/ .

Comment: Ok I read some of it, ill read some more later. Though I do understand what you are saying, now i just have to remember it haha. Thanks again Ana for the help. big props to you!

Answer (score 0):

Use display:table-cell and remove float tag.

```
    #leftnav{
     display:table-cell;
     width:200px;
     height:inherit;
     min-height:inherit;
     height:auto !important;
     background:#FF00FF;
     padding:0;
     overflow:hidden;
      }
    #bodyline{
    display:table-cell;
    width:780px;
    height:800px;
    min-height:800px;
    height:auto !important;
    background:#00FF40;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: may i ask what the two difference are, and what are the benefits? I would just like to know for knowledge purposes. Thanks Santosh